# How to hide a download path of a file with Nodejs and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have a situation where I want to hide the source path or download path of a file in my server from displaying on html. However, user is still be able to download it.

Any plugin for this? It's build with Nodejs and Express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should create an API for it? Then you wont give away your file/folder structure.

```
router.get('/api/download-file', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(your_file, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'your_file_type'}})
})
```